# Some category archive pages are displaying a blank page - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I have an issue with Wordpress categories: 3 of the 20 archive category pages show a blank page :

```
https://www.eres-group.com/category/fiches-pratiques
https://www.eres-group.com/category/fiches-pratiques/optimisation/
https://www.eres-group.com/category/fiches-pratiques/fiscalite/
```

All the other category pages are fine.

My permalinks are set on:

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

I tried : 
- Updating the permalinks
- Updating and checking the categories names and slugs
- Checking my `.htaccess` file for a bad redirection
- Deactivate Yoast SEO

... and still I get a blank page.

Comment: What happens when you enable error messages in the wp-config.php file? define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: Something about a contruct method called for wp_widget in most_popular_tags being obsolete... And to use _construct() instead. (Sorry i translated if from french) 

But this error message shows on every pages so i don't know if it's relevant.

Comment: Try turning off/deactivating all of your plugins and then reload the page.  Also, you can use this plugin to see which template files are included, which may help you find where it is breaking: https://wordpress.org/plugins/show-current-template/

Comment: Great thank you! It was an optimisation tool (minifying js) included in the Autoptimise plugin...